# VBA To Increment Sheets With The Same Name By 1

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a spreadsheet that parses a HL7 message string using "|" as a delimiter. The String that comes before the first "|" becomes the sheet name (Segment). The code executes on each line of the string (Each segment is parsed). The problem is that sometimes there are multiple segments with the same name. So instead of a new sheet being created, all segments are lumped into the same sheet with that name. What I am trying to do is have the code create a new sheet for each segment and if there it is already present, add sheet name with an incremented number.

Sample Message:

```
MSH|^~\&|SR|500|CL|500|20140804150856-0500||SIU^S14|5009310|P|2.3|||AL|NE|USA
SCH|10262|10262|""|S14^(SCHEDULED)^L|44950^APPENDECTOMY^C4||^^^201408081345-0500^^^^^^2||30|MIN^MINUTES|^^^201408081345-0500^201408081415-0500|10000000034^ROISTAFF^CHIEF^O||||||||
PID|1|5000|50^^^USVHA&&0363^NI^FACILITY ID&500&L^^20140804~666^^^USSSA&&0363^SS^FACILITY ID&500&L~^^^USDOD&&0363^TIN^VA FACILITY ID&500&L~^^^USDOD&&0363^FI^FACILITY ID&500&L~736^^^USVHA&&0363^PI^VA FACILITY ID&500&L|736|DATA^PATIENT^^^^^L||19540214|M|||123 main Street^^SW RS^FL^33332^USA^P^^~^^^^^^N|||||||4221^764|666|||||N||||||N||
PV1|1|I|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||500|
OBX|1|CE|^SPECIALTY^||^GENERAL||||||S|||||
OBX|2|CE|^PATIENT CLASS^||^INPATIENT^L||||||S|||||
DG1|1|I9|540.1|ABSCESS OF APPENDIX||P
DG1|2|I9||APPENDICITIS||PR
RGS|1|A|
AIS|1|A|44950^APPENDECTOMY^C4||||
AIP|1|A|1000^PHYSICIAN^KT^|^SURGEON^99||||PENDING
AIP|2|A|1000^NURSE^ONE^|^1ST ASST.^99||||PENDING
AIP|3|A|1000^NURSE^TWO^|^2ND ASST.^99||||PENDING
AIP|4|A|1000^ATTENDING^ONE^|^ATT. SURGEON^99||||PENDING
AIP|5|A|115^DATA^PROVIDERONE^|^PRIN. ANES.^99||||PENDING
AIP|6|A|1000^DATA^PATHOLOGIST^|^ANES. SUPER.^||||PENDING
AIL||500^^^OR1|^OPERATING ROOM||||PENDING


Option Explicit

Const HL7_DELIMITER_FIELD = "|"
Const HL7_DELIMITER_SEGMENT = vbLf
Sub DoHL7Parsing(sMessage As String)
    Dim vSegments As Variant, vCurSeg As Variant
    Dim vFields As Variant, rCurField As Range, iIter As Integer
    Dim wsSeg As Worksheet

    vSegments = VBA.Split(sMessage, HL7_DELIMITER_SEGMENT)

For Each vCurSeg In vSegments
        vFields = VBA.Split(vCurSeg, HL7_DELIMITER_FIELD)
        If WorksheetExists(vFields(0), ThisWorkbook) Then
        On Error Resume Next
            For iIter = 1 To UBound(vFields)
                Set rCurField = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(vFields(0)).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                rCurField.Value = vFields(0)
                rCurField.Offset(0, 1).Value = (rCurField.Row - 1)
                rCurField.Offset(0, 2).NumberFormat = "@"
                rCurField.Offset(0, 2).Value = vFields(iIter)
            Next iIter
        On Error Resume Next
        ElseIf Not WorksheetExists(vFields(0), ThisWorkbook) Then
        Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = vFields(0)
         For iIter = 1 To UBound(vFields)
                Set rCurField = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(vFields(0)).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                rCurField.Value = vFields(0)
                rCurField.Offset(0, 1).Value = (rCurField.Row - 1)
                rCurField.Offset(0, 2).NumberFormat = "@"
                rCurField.Offset(0, 2).Value = vFields(iIter)
            Next iIter
        'MsgBox "Invalid or unkown segment: " & vFields(0)
        End If
    Next vCurSeg
On Error Resume Next
End Sub

Public Function WorksheetExists(ByVal WorksheetName As String, Optional InWorkbook As Workbook) As Boolean
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    WorksheetExists = False

    If Not InWorkbook Is Nothing Then
        For Each Sht In InWorkbook.Worksheets
            If Sht.Name = WorksheetName Then WorksheetExists = True
        Next Sht
    Else
        For Each Sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            If Sht.Name = WorksheetName Then WorksheetExists = True
        Next Sht
    End If
 On Error Resume Next
End Function
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to just count the number of sheets whose `Left(ShtName,3)` value is equal to `vFields(0)`. Based on the count, add 1 and append to end of `vField(0)`. With this approach, you don't even need the dirty `On Error Resume Next` because you won't be targeting the same sheet twice, which can bring down your line count considerably.

For the sheet counting, add the following function to your module:

```
Function CountSheetsWithName(ShtName As String) As Long

    Dim WS As Worksheet, Res As Long
    Res = 0
    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Left(WS.Name, 3) = ShtName Then
            Res = Res + 1
        End If
    Next

    CountSheetsWithName = Res

End Function
```

Update your `DoHL7Parsing` subroutine as follows:

```
Sub DoHL7Parsing(sMessage As String)

    Dim vSegments As Variant, vCurSeg As Variant
    Dim vFields As Variant, rCurField As Range, iIter As Integer
    Dim wsSeg As Worksheet, sShtName As String

    vSegments = VBA.Split(sMessage, HL7_DELIMITER_SEGMENT)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each vCurSeg In vSegments
        vFields = VBA.Split(vCurSeg, HL7_DELIMITER_FIELD)
        For iIter = 1 To UBound(vFields)
            sShtName = vFields(0) & (CountSheetsWithName(CStr(vFields(0))) + 1) ' Append the count + 1 to end of name.
            Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = sShtName
            Set rCurField = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sShtName).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            rCurField.Value = vFields(0)
            rCurField.Offset(0, 1).Value = (rCurField.Row - 1)
            rCurField.Offset(0, 2).NumberFormat = "@"
            rCurField.Offset(0, 2).Value = vFields(iIter)
        Next iIter
    Next vCurSeg

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**Result:**

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! However, the form is a template and the expected sheets are already created. So given the sample message The MSH, SCH, PID, PV1 etc sheets are fixed. The DoHL7Parsing routine takes the line and parses it out in the existing sheet. The problem I'm having is lines that are the same such as AIP get lumped into one sheet. What I would like to happen is have AIP1,AIP2,AIP3,AIP4,AIP5 and AIP6. Each with the line parsed out. These are parsed by segment not fields. I want to be able to recognize the existing sheets and create new sheets if multiple segments with the same name are being parsed.